# Why is my answer getting me reputation even though it's not getting more upvotes?

Tags: discussion, answers, reputation, voting

I recently posted [this](https://writing.stackexchange.com/questions/48076/how-do-you-make-characters-change-believably/48079#48079) answer, I'll admit it wasn't an amazing answer but it received 3 upvotes (as of writing this) and I'm glad I was able to be helpful. What I'm confused about though is that since getting those 3 upvotes on 2 occasions I have received a notification that I had more reputation coming from that answer, but it's upvote count remained the same and it wasn't accepted either.

Why is it getting me more reputation then?

Note: I used the bug tag but I'm not sure if it's actually a bug or if it's just odd behavior, that tag can be changed if necessary.

Comment: I removed the [meta-tag:bug] tag and substituted [meta-tag:discussion].

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your answer has 4 upvotes.

And 1 downvote.

Each upvote gains you 10 points.  Each downvote loses you 2 points.  If you get one of each since the last time you checked, the system will tell you you earned 8 points.

Go to your user activity page (click on your rep number on the top menu) and then click on "reputation."  It will detail every up and down you have, by day and question.

Once you hit 750 rep points, you'll be able to see the [vote count totals](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/established-user) for any post.